# How to update value when it changes on the IONIC page?

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I display a JSON Object tab on a ionic page. The display works fine with the initialization data, but when my JSON Object tab is updated with a socket (.ts), the values are not updated on the page (.html).

I want that the view (.html) display and update the current values of my JSON Object, dynamicly, without refresh the page.

**mypage.ts :**

```
joueurs = { "Steve" : { "name" : "Steve", "idgame" : "0000000" } };

constructor (private nav: NavController, private game: GameProvider, private alertCtrl: AlertController, private loadingCtrl: LoadingController, private socket: Socket, private toastCtrl: ToastController) {
    this.CreateSpeedGame();
}

  CreateSpeedGame(){
   ...
   ...
   //When event (socket.io) :
   //update this.joueurs with another data
   ...
   ...
  }
```

**mypage.html :**
I use a Pipe to display a JSON Object

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let j of joueurs | keys" >
      <ion-label>{{ j.key }}</ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

import CommonModule in your Module and use it as

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>{{ joueurs | json  }}</ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

I don't see why it wouldn't update.

Comment: Me too, it doesn't work with this method. I think the update in the socket is not detected by the page. :-/